# How to store more than one virtual currency in SQL

Tags: php, sql

I have a table called `users` which **currently contains column `money`** of type integer which contains the amount of money the user currently has.

However, I would like to expand and have a couple of more currencies that are based on each other.  1 Gold = 10 Silver = 100 Bronze (or something like that).  When you get 100 Bronze, they will convert into 1 Gold.  The same with 10 Bronze = 1 Silver.  **All these currencies have their own column in my table.**  I have a hook function that is called on every request and updates the money, if possible.

I was told though I could use **just one column `money`** and then I can play with variables and take out the different currencies.

But my question is: **What would be the best method?**

In case the latter method is best: How do I put variables to an already existing object (an object which contains user data; I think it’s called `stdClass` or something like that)? `$user->username`, etc.?

Comment: Note that the title of your question is a bit misleading (and contains a typo), because the question is not about 'real' currencies. For real currencies, the relation between them would fluctuate, and thus the required solution would be different.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just store the equivalent number of bronze. Then use the following algorithm to get as much as possible converted to gold, from the remainder as much as possible to silver and the rest stays in bronze:

1. Set the number of gold to zero, silver to zero and bronze to whatever the database says.
2. Set the number of silver equal to the number of bronze divided by 10 (use integer division). Set the number of bronze equal to the number of bronze mod 10.
3. Set the number of gold equal to the number of silver divided by 10 (use integer division). Set the number of silver equal to the number of silver mod 10.

So if you have 9,327 bronze:

1. gold=0, silver=0, bronze=9,327
2. gold=0, silver=932, bronze=7
3. gold=93, silver=2, bronze=7

Comment: Is intval() the way to go to make sure it is a integer division?

Answer (score 0):

I've done something similar before, and I agree that you should just have the one column for "money", and compute other currencies as-needed.  If you had separate columns, you'd have to rely on a trigger or application logic to keep them in-sync.

Answer (score 0):

I would convert everything to bronze and just store that value. Any sort of transactions would also be converted to bronze first. The only time you need to convert to silver or gold would be for display.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to only store all currency in Bronze.

That way if you have 123 Bronze you can convert them

```
123 / 100   //Gold with integer division which should be 1
```

Remaining are  `123 - NumGold * 100` ie **23**

so you have

```
23 / 10  // Silver with integer division should be 2
```

Remaining are  `23 - NumSilver * 10` ie **3** bronze coins.

This was the SQL knows only about Bronze coins and showing them as Gold , Silver is all in the application layer

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer doesn’t account for values over 9999 since it will add 10 more to silver and give a false output.

The best solution is this:

```
var bronze, silver, gold;
var myMoney = 32141; // number from database

bronze = myMoney % 10;
myMoney = (myMoney - bronze) / 10;
silver = myMoney % 10;
gold = (myMoney - silver) / 10;
```

Output:

```
gold = 321
silver = 4
bronze = 1
```

Comment: I believe this is just pseudocode for the accepted answer. Assuming `/` means integer division.